# htaccess rewrite rule to not make domain.com/uk behave like folder?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the domain.com

My problem is that if I write domain.com/uk there is no a folder, and I don't want to have one.
What I want is to still open the domain.com but add the /uk at the end without any `?`
After, using PHP I will get the `uk` and run some ifs.

Is there any way of doing this only for `uk` and `de` and all other to be the standard dir ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?:de|uk)(/.*)?$ $1 [NC,L]
```

Inside PHP you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to check what is the original request URI (whether `/de/` or `/uk/`)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(de|uk)$ index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

As your question is a little open-ended, this may not work for you, but it gives you an idea of what you should be doing. For example, if you want to have routes such as `uk/something`, we're going to need additional rules in there.

In your `index.php` file, you can get the language by using:

```php
$language = $_GET['lang'];
```

Comment: Consider adding boundaries `^$`. Otherwise you'll get false positives like matching on conclu**de** etc.

Comment: Thanks Ravi, amended.